# Leaflet issues in ie8 and chrome errors

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, leaflet

I am attempting to add this example to a content management system.  The mapping feature will then be modified to meet our needs once it works in all 4 browsers.  No i cant give you any more info on the CMS as it is private.  Please dont mention some of the code using the character entities. ex < is & lt;

Ie8 claims L is not defined.
Chrome claims uncaught reference error L is not defined.

However FF21 and Safari 5.1.7 have no issues displaying this example http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

Why is it when the example is inside the CMS some browsers wont display the map.  Is this poor coding from the demo?  Is this a difference of how the scripts are loaded.  What is the best way to go about troubleshooting this?

The doctype is frameset because of the CMS.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet Layers Control Example</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5.1/leaflet.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leafletjs.com/examples/dist/leaflet.ie.css" /></link><![endif]-->

    <style>
        #map {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        .info {
            padding: 6px 8px;
            font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: white;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .info h4 {
            margin: 0 0 5px;
            color: #777;
        }

        .legend {
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: #555;
        }
        .legend i {
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 8px;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">




        var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

        var cloudmade = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &#169; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &#169; 2011 CloudMade',
            key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707',
            styleId: 22677
        }).addTo(map);


        // control that shows state info on hover
        var info = L.control();

        info.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
            this.update();
            return this._div;
        };

        info.update = function (props) {
            this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
                '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
                : 'Hover over a state');
        };

        info.addTo(map);


        // get color depending on population density value
        function getColor(d) {
            return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
                   d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
                   d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
                   d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                   d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                   d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
                   d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                              '#FFEDA0';
        }

        function style(feature) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density)
            };
        }

        function highlightFeature(e) {
            var layer = e.target;

            layer.setStyle({
                weight: 5,
                color: '#666',
                dashArray: '',
                fillOpacity: 0.7
            });

            if (!L.Browser.ie &amp;&amp; !L.Browser.opera) {
                layer.bringToFront();
            }

            info.update(layer.feature.properties);
        }

        var geojson;

        function resetHighlight(e) {
            geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
            info.update();
        }

        function zoomToFeature(e) {
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
        }

        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
                mouseover: highlightFeature,
                mouseout: resetHighlight,
                click: zoomToFeature
            });
        }

        geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
            style: style,
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        }).addTo(map);

        map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Population data &#169; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a>');


        var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

        legend.onAdd = function (map) {

            var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
                labels = [],
                from, to;

            for (var i = 0; i &lt; grades.length; i++) {
                from = grades[i];
                to = grades[i + 1];

                labels.push(
                    '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                    from + (to ? '&#8211;' + to : '+'));
            }

            div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br />');
            return div;
        };

        legend.addTo(map);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMS is probably running in a secure zone (SSL / http**s**://), then the unsecure Leaflet .js and .css resources (http://) won't be loaded in most browsers, and you get some 'L is undefined' error message. There are some browsers that do load unsecure elements.

Try to include the Leaflet resources from a http**s**:// location.

Answer (score 0):

> Please dont mention some of the code using the character entities. ex < is & lt;

And yet your code works fine when I suppress them.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet Layers Control Example</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5.1/leaflet.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leafletjs.com/examples/dist/leaflet.ie.css" /></link><![endif]-->

    <style>
        #map {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        .info {
            padding: 6px 8px;
            font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: white;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .info h4 {
            margin: 0 0 5px;
            color: #777;
        }

        .legend {
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: #555;
        }
        .legend i {
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 8px;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">




        var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

        var cloudmade = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &#169; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &#169; 2011 CloudMade',
            key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707',
            styleId: 22677
        }).addTo(map);


        // control that shows state info on hover
        var info = L.control();

        info.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
            this.update();
            return this._div;
        };

        info.update = function (props) {
            this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
                '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
                : 'Hover over a state');
        };

        info.addTo(map);


        // get color depending on population density value
        function getColor(d) {
            return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
                   d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
                   d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
                   d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                   d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                   d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
                   d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                              '#FFEDA0';
        }

        function style(feature) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density)
            };
        }

        function highlightFeature(e) {
            var layer = e.target;

            layer.setStyle({
                weight: 5,
                color: '#666',
                dashArray: '',
                fillOpacity: 0.7
            });

            if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
                layer.bringToFront();
            }

            info.update(layer.feature.properties);
        }

        var geojson;

        function resetHighlight(e) {
            geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
            info.update();
        }

        function zoomToFeature(e) {
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
        }

        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
                mouseover: highlightFeature,
                mouseout: resetHighlight,
                click: zoomToFeature
            });
        }

        geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
            style: style,
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        }).addTo(map);

        map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Population data &#169; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a>');


        var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

        legend.onAdd = function (map) {

            var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
                labels = [],
                from, to;

            for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                from = grades[i];
                to = grades[i + 1];

                labels.push(
                    '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                    from + (to ? '&#8211;' + to : '+'));
            }

            div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br />');
            return div;
        };

        legend.addTo(map);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Works fine on chrome. [Try it yourself!](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/BbtzF)

Comment: What do you mean suppress them?  Keep in mind that the cms errors if you dont use character codes.

Comment: I mean replacing them by their usual symbols. The code is fine, I think the problem comes from your CMS.